# Heroku error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, heroku

I'm following a tutorial for building a simple Flask app on Heroku. This is the app file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It runs and functions correctly on the local server. But when I push to Heroku and try to open there, I get an error. The problem seems to be:

```
2020-06-18T15:56:34.850459+00:00 app[web.1]: from flask import Flask
2020-06-18T15:56:34.850459+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Yet, flask is in my requirements.txt:

```
click==7.1.2
flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

And it appears to be installed correctly when I push to Heroku:

```
remote: -----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.1
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting click==7.1.2
remote:          Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
remote:        Collecting flask==1.1.2
remote:          Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.11.2
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==1.1.1
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==1.0.1
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: click, itsdangerous, Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, flask
remote:        Successfully installed Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 click-7.1.2 flask-1.1.2 itsdangerous-1.1.0
```

Any ideas?